# How can we write following mysql query in mongodb? I need to search a text by ignoring some characters from username field stored in users collection

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mongodb

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REPLACE(username, '.', '_') = 'username_without_dots'
```

I read about `$replaceAll` but it is not helping.

In my query, first I am replacing existing record and then comparing, e.g there are usernames like

**harry.potter**

**j.k rowling**,

**robert downy jr.**

so what will happen is that DOTs(.) in these names will be replaced by UNDERSCORE( _ ) so the result will be:

**harry_potter**

**j_k rowling**,

**robert downy jr_**

after that comparing with searched string.

So lets say I am searching **harry_potter**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REPLACE(username, '.', '_') = 'harry_potter'
```

Output will be:
**harry.potter**

Comment: you have to replace them or only to search?

Comment: I'm surprised this `where` clause doesn't work in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
db.users.find({$and:[{"username":/^[^.]*$/},{"username":"username_without_dots"} ] } )
```